# Multiple buffering in OpenGL on Windows

Tags: c++, opengl, performance, winapi, double-buffering

1. What is the most common way modern games perform triple buffering ?
2. What does the [SwapBuffers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd369060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) exactly do in terms of OpenGL states ?
3. Is it possible to perform double and triple buffering independently of window system (for example, by manipulating with glDrawBuffer or by using FBO/PBO) ? If so, any hints ?
4. Does 3. even make sense in terms of performance and flexibility ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This quote answers most of your questions:

> You cannot control whether a driver does triple buffering. You could try to implement it yourself using a FBO. But if the driver is already doing triple buffering, your code will only turn it into quadruple buffering. Which is usually overkill.

http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Triple_Buffering

> What does the SwapBuffers exactly do in terms of OpenGL states ?

From what I understand, it doesn't really do anything other than flushing GL and swapping the buffers.

Comment: "You could try to implement it yourself using a FBO."
it says "You could", but would FBO be actually the best approach ?

Comment: @geneotech The best approach seems to involve no FBO - just let the driver do the buffering. Otherwise, a FBO should be ideal.

Comment: That's what I wanted to hear. So, referring to the game development, I should probably implement both double and triple buffering and leave an option in graphics settings, so when the user is aware of his driver settings, he can turn off multiple buffering in my application at all, and let it be done by driver.

Am I right ?

Comment: @geneotech: Or... not. Just let the driver do its job and you do your job. Triple buffering exists to solve a *problem*. If you're not having that problem, then why would you implement it?

Comment: Most driver control panels will have an option to enable triple buffering, so you could point your users at that if they really want to triple buffer.  I would suspect that the driver itself will do a much better job of more optimal triple buffering than any code you would write (and you can be more confident that it would work more consistently on all hardware, which may not be the case with a home-grown version).

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: Duno, i'm just a little bit confused as I usually see there is a possibility to enable triple buffering in modern games' graphics settings, which means these either are able to talk with every driver or implement the technique on their own. I'm just curious what is happening there, and why is an option like this there at all.

Comment: @geneotech: are any of these games using OpenGL, or are the ones you're thinking of using Direct3D?

Comment: @seanmiddleditch: Most of them in fact use Direct3D, I didn't think it may create a difference on this topic. Do you want to say that Direct3D is capable of controlling the driver settings ?

Comment: @genoetech: The APIs are rather different, yes.  D3D10+ explicitly supports triple-buffering in the API through swap-chain specification, and D3D9 allows hinting to the driver that triple-buffering is desired (which may be ignored by the driver).  OpenGL's API is still based on the 1980's pre-composited shared framebuffer graphics model, and hence has a lot of very unfortunate limitations, despite otherwise being more or less up-to-date with modern hardware capabilities.